# Check if an item inside a tuple contains a specific method

Tags: c++, tuples

I have a tuple and I'm trying to call **initialize()** for each object inside the tuple. Now, some objects might not contain that function. I know I can make that work by using C++20 ***requires*** feature to check if a class contains a given function. Unfortunately, I'm using MSVC and it doesn't support that yet.

Is it possible to write that differently ? I can use C++20 but it should compile on MSVC

```
template <class... Args>
struct CustomTuple : std::tuple<Args...> {
  // Calls "initialize() for each item inside the tuple if that function exists"
  template <std::size_t I = 0>
  auto initialize() {
       std::decay_t<decltype(std::get<I>(*this))> item;
       constexpr bool has_initialize = requires() { // doesnt't work on MSVC
           item.initialize(); 
       };
       if constexpr (has_initialize) {
           std::get<I>(*this).initialize();
       }
       if constexpr (I + 1 != sizeof...(Args)) {
           initialize<I + 1>();
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to `requires` yet, then you will have to make use of SFINAE and write a type-trait for detecting whether `initialize()` is a callable member function.

This can be done with [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t), albeit a little awkwardly:

```cpp
#include <type_traits> // std::void_t
#include <utility>     // std::declval

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_initialize_impl : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_initialize_impl<T, 
  std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T&>().initialize())>
> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto has_initialize = has_initialize_impl<T>::value;
```

The above trait checks if any mutable reference `T&` can call a function named `initialize()`. If the expression is well-formed, then `has_initialized` evaluates to `true`; otherwise, it evaluates to `false`.

This can then be used with the rest of your code with little changes:

```cpp
template <class... Args>
struct CustomTuple : std::tuple<Args...> {
  // Calls "initialize() for each item inside the tuple if that function exists"
  template <std::size_t I = 0>
  auto initialize() {
       // Note: no need to construct a temporary/unused 'item' type,
       // we can just use 'tuple_element' here to get the type
       using element_type = typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
       
       if constexpr (has_initialize<element_type >) {
           std::get<I>(*this).initialize();
       }
       if constexpr (I + 1 != sizeof...(Args)) {
           initialize<I + 1>();
    }
  }
};
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/38vP1EWfo)</kbd>

---

If you think you might have a lot more cases where you need to detect functionality, but still won't have C++20 `requires` support, then it might be worthwhile looking into adding the "detected"-idiom + boilerplate into your code, which can be found on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

This behaves identically to what `std::void_t` does, but is more convenient if needed often. This is still more obtuse than c++20's `requires`, but you don't have many options if your compiler does not support this.

With `is_detected_v`, all you will need is to define template type aliases of any expressions that you need to validate, and simply pass it in to the trait.

For example, the above solution can be solved succinctly as:

```cpp
template <typename T>
using detect_initialize = decltype(std::declval<T&>().initialize());

...

if constexpr (is_detected_v<detect_initialize, decltype(item)>) {
    ...
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ze81zMbr9)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Another way with SFINAE (and no recursion)

```
struct low_priority {};
struct high_priority : low_priority {};

template <typename T>
auto initialize_impl(T& t, high_priority) -> decltype(t.initialize())
{ t.initialize(); }

template <typename T>
void initialize_impl(T&, low_priority) { /*Empty*/ }



template <class... Args>
struct CustomTuple : std::tuple<Args...> {
  // Calls "initialize() for each item inside the tuple if that function exists"
  void initialize() {
       std::apply([](auto&... args)
           {
               (initialize_impl(args, high_priority{}), ...);
           },
           *this);
  }
};
```

Note: priority could be replaced by appropriate concept in C++20.

Comment: I like this solution quite a bit; the `high_priority`/`low_priority` approach here is clever! That said, it took me a sec to really understand _why_ this approach requires two types for the expression SFINAE -- which does add a bit of cognitive overhead

Comment: @Human-Compiler: One `if constexpr` with `std::is_invocable` should also do the job to get rid of priority.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own concept instead.

```
template<typename T>
concept has_initialize = requires(T a) {
    a.initialize();
};

template <class... Args>
struct CustomTuple : std::tuple<Args...> {
  // Calls "initialize() for each item inside the tuple if that function exists"
  template <std::size_t I = 0>
  auto initialize() {
       std::decay_t<decltype(std::get<I>(*this))> item;
       if constexpr (has_initialize<decltype(item)>) {
           std::get<I>(*this).initialize();
       }
       if constexpr (I + 1 != sizeof...(Args)) {
           initialize<I + 1>();
    }
  }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rvhPPsqcz

Comment: As stated by @Gärtner, his/her compiler does not support requires.

Answer (score 0):

Using C++17 features and spiting problem into smaller functions:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U = void>
struct has_inistialize_t : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_inistialize_t<T, std::void_t<decltype(
std::declval<T>().initialize())>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
void tryInitialize_helper(T&& x, std::true_type)
{
    std::forward<T>(x).initialize();
}

template<typename T>
void tryInitialize_helper(T&& x, std::false_type)
{}

template<typename T>
void initialize_if_possible(T&& x)
{
    tryInitialize_helper(std::forward<T>(x), has_inistialize_t<T>{});
}

template<typename ...Ts>
void initilize_each_if_possible(std::tuple<Ts...>& t)
{
    std::apply([](auto&... args){(initialize_if_possible(args), ...);}, t);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vcEnjY7vE